# How to avoid a modified .apk or unsigned ios/android app to request my rest API?

Tags: node.js, rest, react-native

I need to find a way to let my `Nodejs` REST Api know if a request is made from the official app released on the appstore/google play in order to avoid someone to modify the code and recompile the app to reverse engeneering my app.

My app is fully developped in `react-native`.

Any suggestion ?